# how do i output the contents of an array line by line to a uitextview?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have an array of items (for this excercise they are order line items), which are strings inserted line by line to an array. How can I display the contents of the array in a textview without the brackets or commas of the array for each line? I guess it would be along the lines of iterate through the array and for each object take the value, convert to a string and add a line break and add that string to a main mutable string and then set the textfield to the contents of the mutable string. But I would like to know how to iterate the array with code and insert the line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?  If the elements of your array are strings as you say at the beginning of your post, this probably gets you what you want.

```
yourTextField.text = [yourArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

Each element in the array will have 'description' called on it during this joining process.  NSStrings return themselves as their description, but if the elements of your array are a type that you created you could always consider overriding 'description' to get the format you want.

Comment: By George that is elegant! For all the solutions out there that have convoluted for loops yours does the whole thing in one short line.  Worked perfectly first time, all I needed to do was set my textfield name and also global instance (singleton?) of my array, e.g., '[NameOfTheGlobalClassIUse sharedInstance].theNameOfTheArrayIUse' in place of 'yourTextField' and 'yourArray' and it worked.

Comment: Thanks!  By the way, if you ever want to do the opposite and take the contents of your text view and make an array of items, check out the componentsSeparatedByString: method of NSString.

Answer (score 2):

So, this outputs the values into a UITextField

```
NSArray *yourArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithItems:@"A", @"B", @"C"];

NSMutableString *arrayValues = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for (uint i=0;[i<[yourArray count];i++)
{
    NSString *myStr = [yourArray itemAtIndex:i];
    [arrayValues append:myStr];
    [arrayValues append:@"\n"];//insert a newline 

}

yourTextField.value=arrayValues;
```

I think this does it, if not, can you explain "*But I would like to know how to iterate the array with code and insert the line breaks.*" more?

Comment: I had problems getting this to work @Lemonsanver, I gave the answer credit to the one line solution below as it solved my problem exactly.